# Version sort (with alphas, betas, etc.) in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, natural-sort, version-sort

How do I sort a list of versions in Ruby? I've seen stuff about natural sort, but this is a step beyond that.

Input is a bunch of strings like this:

```
input = ['10.0.0b12', '10.0.0b3', '10.0.0a2', '9.0.10', '9.0.3']
```

I can almost do it with the [naturally](https://github.com/dogweather/naturally) gem:

```
require 'naturally'
Naturally.sort(input)
=> ["9.0.3", "9.0.10", "10.0.0a2", "10.0.0b12", "10.0.0b3"]
```

Problem: 10.0.0b3 is sorted after 10.0.0b12; 10.0.0b3 should be first.

Anyone have a way that works? Other languages are helpful too!

Comment: Those are extremely atypical version strings. You're not likely to find an off-the-shelf solution; you should write your own.

Comment: I changed it to use Semantic Versioning. That's more typical.

Comment: @MusashiAharon This isn't quite Semantic Versioning. For that you'd want the `b12` `b3`, etc to be preceded by a `-`.

Comment: True. With the hyphen, natural sort works nicely, but this almost-semver system is still pretty common.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ruby ships with the Gem class, which knows about versions:

```
ar = ['10.0.0b12', '10.0.0b3', '10.0.0a2', '9.0.10', '9.0.3']

p ar.sort_by { |v| Gem::Version.new(v) }
# => ["9.0.3", "9.0.10", "10.0.0a2", "10.0.0b3", "10.0.0b12"]
```

Comment: Nice. For what it's worth -- looks like this handles "alpha" and "beta" alphabetically only. That is, `['9.0.10rc2', '9.0.10', '9.0.10rc1', '9.0.10a', '9.0.10test']` yields `["9.0.10a", "9.0.10rc1", "9.0.10rc2", "9.0.10test", "9.0.10"]`. Should be sufficient, since "alpha / beta / pre-release / rc / release" happen to flow alphabetically anyway, but could be quirky if your data deviates too far from that.

Comment: pretty interesting how it works: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/1aa8033952d4eda5ca131039822f9548166ab507/lib/rubygems/version.rb#L336-L361

Answer (score 5):

If you interpret this as "sort by each segment of digits", then the following will handle your example input above:

```
input.map{ |ver| ver.split(%r{[^\d]+}).map(&:to_i) }.zip(input).sort.map(&:last)
=> ["9_0", "9_1", "10_0b3", "10_0b12"]
```

That is,

- for each value, eg `10_0b3`
- split on any length of non-digit characters, eg `["10","0","3"]`
- cast each digit segment to integer, eg `[10,0,3]`
- zip with original input, yields `[[[10, 0, 12], "10_0b12"], [[10, 0, 3], "10_0b3"], [[9, 0], "9_0"], [[9, 1], "9_1"]]`
- sort, by virtue of `[10,0,3] < [10,0,12]`
- get last value of each element, which is the original input value which corresponds to each processed sortable value

Now granted, this is still quite custom -- version numbers as simple as "9_0a" vs "9_0b" won't be handled, both will appear to be [9,0] -- so you may need to tweak it further, but hopefully this starts you down a viable path.

**EDIT:** Example input above changed, so I changed the regex to make sure the digit-matching is greedy, and with that it still holds up:

```
irb(main):018:0> input = ['10.0.0b12', '10.0.0b3', '9.0.10', '9.0.3']
=> ["10.0.0b12", "10.0.0b3", "9.0.10", "9.0.3"]
irb(main):025:0> input.map{ |ver| ver.split(%r{[^\d]+}).map(&:to_i) }.zip(input).sort.map(&:last)
=> ["9.0.3", "9.0.10", "10.0.0b3", "10.0.0b12"]
```

Comment: This does help, but betas aren't the only possible suffix. We could also have alphas like '10.0.0a2' or release candidates like '10.0.0rc1'. If these are side-by-side with the others, the sorting breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case that you are working with NuGet and want to parse, compare or sort by NuGet's peculiar own versioning scheme from Ruby code, there is now this:

https://rubygems.org/gems/nuget_versions

I created it specifically to solve this problem. NuGet's version numbers are a bit weird, they are a superset of SemVer that also permits the use of 4 components instead of 3.