# How do I parse a tab-delimited line that contains a quote?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing, tabs, quotes

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I parse a tab-delimited line that contains a quote character?  This is what's happening to me now ...

```
2.4.0 :003 > line = "11\tDave\tO\"malley"
 => "11\tDave\tO\"malley" 
2.4.0 :004 > CSV.parse(line, col_sep: "\t")
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1912:in `block (2 levels) in shift'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1868:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1868:in `block in shift'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1828:in `loop'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1828:in `shift'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1770:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1784:in `to_a'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1784:in `read'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1324:in `parse'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in    `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Although teh example illustrates my point, I can't easily control the input coming in.  So, although an answer coudl be< "Remove all quotes from teh string before parsing," I want to preserve the data as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a malformed document if you're trying to adhere to the CSV standard. Instad you might just brute-force it and pray there's no tabs in the data itself:

```
line.split(/\t/)
```

The CSV parsing library comes in handy when you're dealing with data like this:

```
"1\t2\t\"3a\t3b\"\t4"
```

**Update:** If you're prepared to abuse the CSV library a little then you can do this:

```
CSV.parse("11\tDave\tO\"malley", col_sep: "\t", quote_char: "\0")
```

That basically kills quote detection, so if there is other data that depends on that being processed correctly this may not work out.

Comment: I didn't want to get too into the weeds in my question but I have a generic function that is actually CSV.parse(line, col_sep: delimiter) in which the delimiter could be a comma or tab .  are there other delimiters?  are you saying there's no way to get this to work using the CSV.parse method?

Comment: The CSV library can only handle data which conforms at least roughly to the CSV "standard". Since your data doesn't you're left with a number of sub-optimal solutions. I've added an alternative to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

"11\tDave\tO\"malley" is not valid CSV data. Strangely enough, the answer is to use two double-quotes, and to double quote each element

```
2.3.1 :001 > require 'csv'
 => true 
2.3.1 :002 > line = "\"11\"\t\"Dave\"\t\"O\"\"malley\""
 => "\"11\"\t\"Dave\"\t\"O\"\"malley\"" 
2.3.1 :003 > puts line # for clarity
"11"    "Dave"  "O""malley"
 => nil 
2.3.1 :004 > CSV.parse(line, col_sep: "\t")
 => [["11", "Dave", "O\"malley"]]
```

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-3, paragraph 7, for the explanation.